# Mercurial server files different from clients files

Tags: mercurial

Firstly, I am still quite new to Mercurial and version control in general.

We have a setup here of 2 developers and a server. We noticed an issue today of some changes that I pushed to the server yesterday, the other developer when he pulled it didn't have these changes. Eventually I decided to check on the server what the status of the file in question was, and surprisingly the file didn't even exist on the server's repository. The weird thing is, the other developer created this file at some point and pushed it to the server and I received it through pulling it, so surely it must have been on the server at one point? On both our machine's tortoise hg has a tick next to the file so its part of the repository and committed.

Seems that the file not being on the server might be why the changes I have made to the file aren't reaching the other developer.

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Without logs I'll just say "It's impossible, if your push was executed without errors".

If you pushed with errors and pulled **only** later - you have to have anonymous branch and additional head in your repo for diverged changes

Answer (score 0):

A tick in TortoiseHg **does not** mean that the file has been committed. A checkbox will show up for files when you are looking at the *working directory* and a tick in the checkbox indicates that when you click the "Commit" button the file will be included in the commit.

Files which already exist in the repository (or have been staged via `hg add`, `hg mv`, `hg cp`, etc) will be ticked by default but files which have not yet been added to the repository will not be ticked. If you tick a file which has not yet been added then TortoiseHg will add it before committing.